CreateFile C:\mnt: The system cannot find the file specified
Using VScode with WSL terminal in windows machine, I am using docker desktop to copy some file avaible in my windows location which I wanted to copy into the container running over the docker desktop.
It is not clear why mnt is looking after c:\ where as I am using WSL which uses the mnt for mounting the windows file system and after that c drive once which you can see below: (where as i could easily do the listing on the same file)

Please help if i am making any mistake here.

docker.exe is a native Windows executable so it isn't going to understand the WSL paths. Use C:\Users\igour\... instead.

Can we install docker on ubuntu (WSL) as native? and is it possible that it would pick the windows docker desktop?

I just resolve this docker.exe with from the section -> settings -> resources-> WSL integration -> enable Ubuntu.
